# jquery - Animated return to top of page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate a scroll effect to take a user to the top of the page when clicking on an element. A bit like anchoring to the top of the page but smoother.

I've seen this done (can't remember where though).

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the `scrollTop` property to `0`, like this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
```

Comment: `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },{duration: 500, queue: false );`  just to be sure

Answer (score 4):

you can try this:

```
 $('#somewhere').click(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code on document load, for example to animate to top

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
```

And you can animate to an especific element, like

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.my-element').offset().top }, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used Ariel Flesler's localscroll plugin to do this many times... http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll

Comment: A plugin is *really* overkill here, since it can be done with the very simple code in my answer...no plugins, just jQuery core required.