# Jquery Animated Back to Top

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I'm currently trying to make a button which will take the user back to the top of the page, but animated. Making the page scroll back up to the top when the button is clicked. I did a search on here and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518862/jquery-animated-return-to-top-of-page-on-click)..

And I have attempted to make a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HX3ww/1/) of this using the following...

**CSS**

```
html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:2000px;
}

body {
height:2000px;   
}

#blue-box {
position:fixed;
width:100px;
height:70px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top:50px;
background-color:blue;     
}

#blue-box h1{
font-family:Constantia;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
margin-top:5px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="blue-box">
<h1>Back To Top</h1>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var away = false;

$('#blue-box').click(function() {
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work and I'm wondering whether I have missed something out or done something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `});` at the end of your script. Adding it [solves your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/HX3ww/2/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var away = false;

    $('#blue-box').click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
    });
});  // <-- Here.
```

That's a good example of why indenting your code properly is important. It makes this kind of error far more difficult to miss.

Comment: Doh! Thanks, I'm a complete novice at JavaScript and that would've taken me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close your $(document).ready

http://jsfiddle.net/HX3ww/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is also a slight variation where the button only fades in once you start scrolling down the page and disappears once you return to the top of the page http://jsfiddle.net/b4M66/

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();    
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#toTop').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
    });    
});​
```

CSS:

```
#toTop { position: fixed; bottom: 50px; right: 30px; width: 84px; background-color: #CCC; cursor: pointer; display: none; }​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toTop">Back to Top</div>​
```